# Show that if $2^t \le (t+1)^n, n\ge 5$, then $ t \le n^2-1$

Tags: inequality

I am reading a book in which the following is just stated without proof: If 
 $2^t \le (t+1)^n, n\ge 5$, then$ t \le n^2-1$. I've tried expanding the RHS using the binomial theorem, but I haven't gotten anywhere with it. I'm especially puzzled by the condition that $n\ge5$. A crude way would be to plug in $n=5$, which I am soon to attempt, but I would like to know if there is another way. Any hints in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $t\ln 2\leq n\cdot\ln(t+1)$.

Comment: why the $n + ln(t+1)$ and not $nln(t+1)$?

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Lapsus calami. Corrected.

Comment: I still don't see how $n \ge 5$ is related to this

Comment: @TheDeadLegend You have a full answer now. OP wanted a hint, so my answer is left on the desired level,

Answer (score 1):

Assume $t>n^2-1$.
Then $t\ge n^{1.97}$ and
from
$$t\ln 2\le n\ln(t+1) $$
we get
$$n^{1.97}\ln 2< t\ln 2\le n\ln(n^2) =2n\ln n$$
so
$$\tag1n^{0.97}\le \frac 2{\ln 2}\cdot\ln n<3\ln n.$$
But the power on the left grows faster than the log on the right, making $(1)$  false for $n\ge 5$.

We conclude that $t\le n^2-1$ if $n\ge 5$.

Comment: How did you get $t \ln  2\leq  n \ln \left(n^2\right)$

Comment: @Lozenges "Assume $t>n^2-1$".

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke the inequality going in the wrong direction

Comment: @Lozenges It is *reductio ad absurdum* method.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke We have $t \ln  2\leq  n \ln (t+1)$ and $\ln (t+1)>\ln \left( n^2\right)$. How do we get $t \ln  2\leq  n \ln \left(n^2\right)$ ?

Comment: @Lozenges You are right! So there is an issue with this proof.